# AutoCAD 2006 vs. 2012

Tags: graphics, 3d, autocad

I'm looking to learn AutoCAD. I have found several videos online that relate to 2006 AutoCAD - but is there a difference to any of of the versions. I have seen job postings asking to know AutoCAD 2008 -- what happens if I only know 2011 or even 2010. Can I work with 2008? Is there a difference to any of this versions or years?

Comment: That's a programming related Q&A site and your question is off-topic.

Comment: Have a look at the questions and answers from this search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocad?sort=votes&pagesize=50 You will find a lot of leads to good resources in those

Comment: I would say you're fine. Going forward is far easier than backwards. In fact, I would say the earlier the better. I was trained in classes on 2008, both AC and REVIT, but forced myself to do all my work in 2010+. It's true that as time goes by more co.s will move to newer versions, but that doesn't make economic sense for everyone. In short, if you can use 2006, you'll be great at 2008+. But here's the most important piece of advice for 2010 and beyond:Don't fight the ribbon, use it - it's beneficial, but at the same time, stay true to command line input - to me it makes all the difference.

Answer (score -1):

AutoCAD is a lot like Windows... They have major releases and minor releases, so the change from 2006-2007 was a significant change.  They roll out a major release every couple years or so.  Still, it just depends on what you're doing.  If you've got to draw a line, it's drawing a line, and that doesn't change a lot from one release to another.  Some companies use the "features" of the software, but lots of them don't.  My advice: get an account with Autodesk University [here](http://au.autodesk.com/) and click through the online classes.  Look for some basic AutoCAD classes.  It will really help you learn about the software and the changes made from one release to another.  Also: If you get an interview for a CAD job, they will probably give you a test... usually it's just drawing something in CAD from a piece of paper.  I had one of these where I had to use a version of AutoCAD called Architectural Desktop.  I had never even seen Architectural Desktop before, so I asked the person interviewing me, "Where do I start?" He showed my how to start, and I actually got the job.  That was 7 years ago and I still work for that company today.  Use the free tutorials to acquaint yourself with the software, but don't be intimidated by it.  If you get as far as testing in an interview, do your best, and don't be afraid to ask questions.

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly 2006 was still a version without the ribbon interface. In any case, the most significant change in user interface in the recent years was exactly that - caused quite a bit of stir when it was first introduced, and many drafters still switch to "old" toolbar.

As far as changes go, yes, there are quite a few. But as Asheville said, they more relate to some advanced features of the software, which at this time you will probably not be using. My advice would be to start with some of the newer versions ("the ribbon" ones) and adjust yourself to it. After you've grasped the fundamentals, and found your way around, and wish to expand your knowledge in a more systematic way (although we all know this almost never works :) I would go to one of the either; "Autocad xxxx Bible", or "Mastering Autocad xxxx" books where xxxx signifies the version. They are quite heavy (figuratively and literally) and you can skim through as you progress. Most of the things in there you probably won't need, unless you find yourself working in a large draft office which has it's own way of organizing data, drawing styles, ...

Autocad forums are also a good place to ask questions (search first !) ... the community there is quite helpful.